# Android Jelly Bean WebView not loading any images, why?

Tags: android, webview

I wrote a simple Android App which display simple webpages in WebView. But I found that the **img** tags in my webpages are not shown in my Jelly Bean emulator and Sumsung device(GT-I9308). And it works well in other Android versions(tested in Lolipop, Mashmallow) and PC browser. Please help!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style></style>
 </head>
<body>
 <img class="userLogo" _v-361208f4="" src="https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80&size=b9999_10000&sec=1492674362&di=5540ee2b22a759215fe58c6b15b39cfc&imgtype=jpg&er=1&src=http%3A%2F%2Ffun.youth.cn%2Fyl24xs%2F201703%2FW020170312401554414982.png">
 <img class="userLogo" _v-361208f4="" src="https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80&size=b9999_10000&sec=1492079646023&di=2c270483895b7c785f12073a0f452455&imgtype=0&src=http%3A%2F%2Ffun.youth.cn%2Fyl24xs%2F201703%2FW020170306367477164516.png">
 <img class="userLogo" _v-361208f4="" src="https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80&size=b9999_10000&sec=1492079646021&di=a8ad07fa3d670acb8dc870015d339633&imgtype=0&src=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.mnw.cn%2F2017%2F0227%2F1488186398602.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried:

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

And still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because webview not support in Android 4.3 and older